# Formatting negative numbers with brackets

Tags: r, negative-number

I would like to format my negative numbers in "Accounting" format, i.e. with brackets.
For example, I would like to format -1000000 as (1,000,000).

I know the way of introducing thousands-separator:

```
 prettyNum(-1000000, big.mark=",",scientific=F)
```

However, I am not sure how to introduce the brackets. I would like to be able to apply the formatting to a whole vector, but I would want only the negative numbers to be affected. Not that after introducing the thousands separator, the vector of numbers is now a **characater vector**, example:

```
 "-50,000" "50,000"  "-50,000" "-49,979" "-48,778" "-45,279" "-41,321"
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you applying this to a vector of numerics of a vector of character values representing numbers?

Comment: Well, as I said above, the initial vector is a numeric vector. But when I introduce the thousands separator, the vector becomes a vector of character values representing numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy approach is using `paste0` and `sub`. Here's a simple function for this:

```
my.format <- function(num){
  ind <- grepl("-", num)
  num[ind] <-  paste0("(", sub("-", "", num[ind]), ")")
  num
}

> num <- c("-50,000", "50,000",  "-50,000", "-49,979", "-48,778", "-45,279", "-41,321")
> my.format(num)
[1] "(50,000)" "50,000"   "(50,000)" "(49,979)" "(48,778)" "(45,279)" "(41,321)"
```

If you want to reverse the situation, let's say, you have a vector like this:

```
num2 <- my.format(num)
```

and you want to replace `(·)` by `-`, then try

```
sub(")", "", sub("\\(", "-", num2))
```

Comment: Well, it works for negative numbers. But when I apply it to a vector of numbers, it will transform even the positive numbers as well...

Answer (score 4):

You can try my package [formattable](https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable) which has a built-in function `accounting` to apply accounting format to numeric vector.

```
> # devtools::install_github("renkun-ken/formattable")
> library(formattable)
> accounting(c(123456,-23456,-789123456))
[1] 123,456.00       (23,456.00)      (789,123,456.00)
```

You can print the numbers as integers:

```
> accounting(c(123456,-23456,-789123456), format = "d")
[1] 123,456       (23,456)      (789,123,456)
```

These numbers work with arithmetic calculations:

```
> money <- accounting(c(123456,-23456,-789123456), format = "d")
> money
[1] 123,456       (23,456)      (789,123,456)
> money + 5000
[1] 128,456       (18,456)      (789,118,456)
```

It also works in `data.frame` printing:

```
> data.frame(date = as.Date("2015-01-01") + 1:10, 
    balance = accounting(cumsum(rnorm(10, 0, 100000))))
         date      balance
1  2015-01-02  (21,929.80)
2  2015-01-03 (246,927.59)
3  2015-01-04 (156,210.85)
4  2015-01-05 (135,122.80)
5  2015-01-06 (199,713.06)
6  2015-01-07  (91,938.03)
7  2015-01-08  (34,600.47)
8  2015-01-09   147,165.57
9  2015-01-10   180,443.31
10 2015-01-11   251,141.04
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way, without regex:

```
x <- c(-50000, 50000, -50000, -49979, -48778, -45279, -41321)
x.comma <- prettyNum(abs(x), big.mark=',')
ifelse(x >= 0, x.comma, paste0('(', x.comma, ')'))
# [1] "(50,000)" "50,000"   "(50,000)" "(49,979)" "(48,778)" "(45,279)" "(41,321)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that gives the leading spaces:

```
x <- c(-10000000, -4444, 1, 333)

num <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", prettyNum(abs(x), ,big.mark=",", scientific=F))
num[x < 0] <- sprintf("(%s)", num[x < 0])
sprintf(paste0("%0", max(nchar(as.character(num))), "s"), num)


## [1] "(10,000,000)" "     (4,444)" "           1" "         333"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?:

```
a <- prettyNum(-1000000, ,big.mark=",",scientific=F)
paste("(", sub("-", "", a), ")", sep = "")
```

Comment: Well, it works for negative numbers. But when I apply it to a vector of numbers, it will transform even the positive numbers as well...